# Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onSubmit is not a function when using redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I'm working with a React.js frontend, and when I try to login or signup I get the below error when clicking the `login` or `Sign up` buttons.

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onSubmit is not a function
```

The stacktrace is pointing to the following file,

**/src/containers/Login/index.js**

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { css, StyleSheet } from 'aphrodite';
import Input from '../../components/Input';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    maxWidth: '500px',
    padding: '3rem 4rem',
    margin: '2rem auto',
  },
});

type Props = {
  onSubmit: () => void,
  handleSubmit: () => void,
  submitting: boolean,
}

class LoginForm extends Component {
  props: Props

  handleSubmit = (data) => this.props.onSubmit(data);
  // handleSubmit: (data) => this.props.onSubmit(data);


  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <form
        className={`card ${css(styles.card)}`}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}
      >
        <h3 style={{ marginBottom: '2rem', textAlign: 'center' }}>Login to Sling</h3>
        <Field name="email" type="text" component={Input} placeholder="Email" />
        <Field name="password" type="password" component={Input} placeholder="Password" />
        <button
          type="submit"
          disabled={submitting}
          className="btn btn-block btn-primary"
        >
          {submitting ? 'Logging in...' : 'Login'}
        </button>
        <hr style={{ margin: '2rem 0' }} />
        <Link to="/signup" className="btn btn-block btn-secondary">
          Create a new account
        </Link>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Required';
  }
  return errors;
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  validate,
})(LoginForm);
```

specifically the below line,

```
  handleSubmit = (data) => this.props.onSubmit(data);
```

Again, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Finally, the entire project can be found [here](https://github.com/ipatch/kegcopr-frontend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handleSubmit` is a prop "injected" into the Component by redux-form, `onSubmit` is not... you either have to make sure you're supplying it yourself or just handle the form submit within `LoginForm#handleSubmit`

You can also do it this way: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1163

references:

- http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/faq/HandleVsOn.md/

Answer (score 1):

In your `App/index.js`, you did

```
 <RedirectAuthenticated path="/login" component={Login} {...authProps} />
```

You can see you did not pass a `onSubmit` function to the Login component

You can fix it by making these changes to `App/index.js`

```
// add this function
const LoginComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Login onSubmit={() => { console.log("hi") }} />
    )   
}

class App extends Component {
    ...

   render() {
     ....
     <RedirectAuthenticated path="/login" component={LoginComponent} {...authProps} />
```

In this case, you will see 'hi' printed to the dev console.